# How to show Odoo tutorial pop up when user loggins

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-10

My requirement is to call tutorial popup in Odoo10 website moudule to be appear on dashboard module once user login

Answer (score 0):

Please check with **auth_signup** module of odoo it will redirect after login.

Check the template and modified it.